# Animation in Oncreate() not stopping in android

Tags: android, android-animation

**Want to Do : i want to have an Internet check on Start of An app and if it doesn't finds then on clicking Positive button it should go to setting of wifi & if User ON the wifi then on coming back to App i want the dialog box to be dismiss and Animation start else it again show how the Internet Dialog Box .**

***What i have done* : I have placed the Internet Check Dialog in OnResume() and animation code in OnCreate .**

***Issue is* : on start of my App, when it check Wifi connection ,But it also run all the animation code in Oncreate() in continuity instead of running it only after Internet Connection**

**OnCreate Code :**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.grow_from_middle, R.anim.shrink_to_middle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_csplogin);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        mobileEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobileText);
        nameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        employerEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.employerText);
        noEmployerCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.noEmployercheckboxid);
        employerSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.employer_spinner_id);
        noEmployerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutCheckbox);

        init();


        if (myPrefs.getOrgValidated() == false) {
            new OrganisationValidationTask(CSPLoginActivity.this).execute();
        }



        isdeviceValidated = myPrefs.getIsDeviceValidated();
        isLoggedIn = myPrefs.getIsLogIn();
        if (isdeviceValidated) {
            startLoginActivity();
        }



            final RelativeLayout LoginBox = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LoginBox);

            LoginBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Animation animTranslate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CSPLoginActivity.this, R.anim.translate);
            animTranslate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

                    LoginBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Animation animFade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CSPLoginActivity.this, R.anim.fade);
                    LoginBox.startAnimation(animFade);

                    showSingleChoice();
                }

            });
            ImageView imgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imgLogo.startAnimation(animTranslate);

            isdeviceValidated = myPrefs.getIsDeviceValidated();
            isLoggedIn = myPrefs.getIsLogIn();


            if (!isLoggedIn) {
                // display login screen

                if (Utils.isNetworkConnected(this)) {

                    if (isdeviceValidated) {
                        // to display user details
//                    displayUserDetails();

                        if (!isMyServiceRunning()) {
                            Utils.startLocationPollerAndWakeupService(this);
                        }

                    }
                }
            } else if (isLoggedIn && isdeviceValidated) {
                // skip login screen
                if (!isMyServiceRunning()) {
                    Utils.startLocationPollerAndWakeupService(this);
                }
                startLoginActivity();

            }

        }
```

**OnResume**

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

            if(Utils.isNetworkConnected(this)) {

            }else{
                showWifiAlert();
            }
        }
```

**Checking Internet Connection Dialog Box**:

```
 private void showWifiAlert(){
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(CSPLoginActivity.this)

                .content("Unable to validate device as Internet not available")
                .title("Alert !")
                .positiveText("OK")
                .negativeText("Cancel")
                .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNegative(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        finish();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .cancelable(false)
                .show();


    }
```

Please Help  , How to achieve what i want to do .

Comment: try put your `imgLogo.startAnimation(animTranslate);` inside `Utils.isNetworkConnected(this)` loop

Comment: @Mohit : It worked for me . Thanks Alot . You saved .  I would request u too please answer the question instead comment so that it would help btoh of us .

Comment: your welcome...well I was not sure about the answer so i didnt posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing the onResume method code as following:

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

            if(Utils.isNetworkConnected(this)) {
                imgLogo.startAnimation(animTranslate);
            }else{
                showWifiAlert();
            }
        }
```

Let me know if this works for you.